# Play an ivr based on hangup cause

Tags: freeswitch

Is there anyway to play an ivr based on Hangupcause ?

Right now i have tried below dialplan but seems like its not working.
So please suggest if there is any other way i can achieve it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="freeswitch/xml">
<section name="dialplan" description="Custom_dialplan">
<context name="default">
<extension name="123456">
<condition field="destination_number" expression="123456">
<action application="set" data="effective_destination_number=123456"/>
<action application="set" data="transfer_on_fail=RECOVERY_ON_TIMER_EXPIRE auto_cause xml error"/>
<action application="bridge" data="sofia/gateway/Dummy_Gateway/123456"/>
<action application="log" data="AFTER BRIDGE"/>
</condition>
</extension>
</context>
<context name=error">
<action application="log" data="AFTER BRIDGE2"/>
<extension name="RECOVERY_ON_TIMER_EXPIRE" continue="true">
<action application="log" data="AFTER BRIDGE3"/>
<condition field="${originate_disposition}" expression="RECOVERY_ON_TIMER_EXPIRE"  continue="false" break="on-true">
<action application="log" data="AFTER BRIDGE4"/>
<action application="playback" data="/usr/local/freeswitch/sounds/en/us/callie/notinservice.wav"/>
</condition>
</extension>
</context>
</section>
</document>
```

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, you have done few mistakes in your dialplan while it is significant:

1. Before use transfer_on_fail you should set up another obligatory options follows:

   ```
   <action application="set" data="continue_on_fail=true"/>
   <action application="set" data="failure_causes=RECOVERY_ON_TIMER_EXPIRE"/>
   ```
2. To remove that logging option BRIDGE due to it's useless and it will never be handled.
3. I would like to draw your attention the dialplan has strict structure, so you can't insert options/actions wherever you want. First of all, you should remove all logging from the context ERROR

-- The sequence is going to be: context -> extension --> condition --> action (s). Thus you have setup the condition follows with the action playing announcement.

--!-- You have taken call handling in your hands, so please manage the process. After your platform had played to leg A you have to instruct FreeSWITCH terminating the call (it must follow "playback"):

```
    <action application="hangup" data="NORMAL_CLEARING"/>
```

However, I assume your dialplan won't work ever because RECOVERY_ON_TIMER_EXPIRE is the status of Freeswitch State Machine which appear when SIP 408. You should use Q.850 hangup cause in dialplan instead, so try replacing it with NO_USER_RESPONSE.
You may find Q.850 hangup cause table [here](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Hangup+Cause+Code+Table)